# Elastic Search - Multi Word Exact Match

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to adjust the following query so it exactly matches multiple words. Whenever I try this it seems to tokenize the strings and then search. How can I specify for a particular substring that it must be an exact match?

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "string OR string2 OR this is my multi word string",
            "fields": ["title","description"]
         }
     }
}
```

My mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "indexname": {
       "properties": {
          "title": {
          "type": "multi_field",
          "fields": {
                 "title": {"type": "string"},
                 "original": {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
          }
       },
       "location": {
           "type": "geo_point"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping????

Comment: I've posted my mapping.

Answer (score 0):

By default the QuerySring and match queries are analyzed.So use terms query.unfortunately we cannot use multiple fields in term query.So use bool query for that.Please try bellow query..

```
 {
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "term": {
              "title": {
                 "value": "string OR string2 OR this is my multi word string"
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "description": {
                 "value": "string OR string2 OR this is my multi word string"
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: I'm a bit confused because searching in multiple fields as I did it was working for single terms. The problem was with a multi word term. It is also producing impossible results.

Comment: better post a example with sample data and query..!